# Strange error message

Tags: couchdb

I have defined the following view:

```
{ "_id":"_design/test",
  "language":"javascript",
  "views":
  { "test": 
    { "map": "function(doc) { for (var k in doc.data) emit(doc.data[k],null);}",
      "options": {"collation":"raw"}
    }
  }
}
```

When querying the view without any parameters, I get the expected result (sorted as "AB...ab" instead of "aAbB" because I specified a raw collation):

```
http://localhost:5985/test/_design/test/_view/test

{"total_rows":13,"offset":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"-","key":"A","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"B","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"C","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"D","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"E","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"F","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"a","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"b","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"c","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"d","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"e","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"f","value":null},
  {"id":"-","key":"g","value":null}
]}
```

I then use `startkey` and `endkey` to ask for the range between `B` and `a`, and I expect to receive keys `BCDEFa`, but instead I receive the following error message:

```
http://localhost:5985/test/_design/test/_view/test?startkey=%22B%22&endkey=%22a%22

{ "error": "query_parse_error",
  "reason": "No rows can match your key range, reverse your start_key and 
             end_key or set descending=true"
}
```

Why does it say that no rows can match the key range, when rows B,C,D,E,F and a will match ?

EDIT: I have a single document (revision and ID omitted):

```
{ "_id": "-", 
  "_rev": "-", 
  "data": [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" ] 
}
```

Comment: What version of CouchDB are you running? I do not get that error on v1.0.1

Comment: Can you include some sample documents as well?

Comment: Can you include the command you use for querying? Maybe there is some quoting problem. This is the most typical error in this cases.

Comment: @Dominic Barnes: I edited the question to include the single sample document. @Marcello Nuccio: the queries are already provided above, as they appear in the CouchDB log.

Comment: This may indeed be a proper CouchDB bug. It seems reasonable that the code to sort views is different from the input-validation code for HTTP queries. Perhaps the latter did not get the `{"collation":"raw"}` memo.

Comment: You've got a lot of reputation so I assume you know what you're doing. But I've got to say, raw collation may not provide any measurable performance boost. The only reason I can think to use it is to be compatible with other software, such as Unix tools that expect ASCII collation, etc. Anyway, see my comment to the answer below. If you file a bug they'll fix it!

Comment: @jhs: I'm using a raw collation for that view because I need the key order to be reasonably predictable on the client side, and the ICU order just blows my mind. I neither expect nor observe any performance gain. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking again through wads of documentation and asking around, it seems that this behavior is unintended. I have [submitted a JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1228) for this. I currently have no general-purpose workaround to suggest, though I have been able to work around the problem in my specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that I experience the same behaviour in version 1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.

To elaborate:

```
curl http://localhost:5984/test/_design/test/_view/view?startkey=%22B%22\&endkey=%22a%22
```

returns the error

```
{"error":"query_parse_error","reason":"No rows can match your key range, reverse your start_key and end_key or set descending=true"}
```

while

```
curl http://localhost:5984/test/_design/test/_view/view?startkey=%22B%22\&endkey=%22D%22
```

gives

```
{"total_rows":12,"offset":1,"rows":[
```

{"id":"stuff","key":"B","value":null},
{"id":"stuff","key":"C","value":null},
{"id":"stuff","key":"D","value":null}
]}

So quoting issues don't look to be the problem.

I am using a single document:

```
{
```

"_id": "stuff",
   "_rev": "2-0507028fcab427a1b28ed6b3d4a6c05e",
   "data": [
       "A",
       "B",
       "C",
       "D",
       "E",
       "F",
       "a",
       "b",
       "c",
       "d",
       "e",
       "f"
   ]
}

Comment: and @Victor, I suggest you post this to JIRA, or at least get the ball rolling in the users mailing list. Based on the description, it seems likely to be a bug. If you would be nice enough to put it in JIRA, doubtless a developer will be nice enough to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

**I have found this tip on http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html (paragraph Reversed Results).
hoping that could help you.**

Reversed Results

To retrieve view results in reverse order, use the `descending=true` query parameter. If you are using a `startkey` parameter, you will find that CouchDB returns different rows or no rows at all. What’s up with that?

It’s pretty easy to understand when you see how view query options work under the hood. A view is stored in a tree structure for fast lookups. Whenever you query a view, this is how CouchDB operates:

Starts reading at the top, or at the position that `startkey` specifies, if present.

Returns one row at a time until the end or until it hits `endkey`, if present.

If you specify `descending=true`, the reading direction is reversed, *not* the sort order of the rows in the view. In addition, the same two-step procedure is followed.

Say you have a view result that looks like this:

KeyValue





`0``"foo"`

`1``"bar"`

`2``"baz"`

Here are potential query options: `?startkey=1&descending=true`. What will CouchDB do? See #1 above: it jumps to `startkey`, which is the row with the key `1`, and starts reading backward until it hits the end of the view. So the particular result would be:

KeyValue





`1``"bar"`

`0``"foo"`

This is very likely not what you want. To get the rows with the indexes `1` and `2` in reverse order, you need to switch the `startkey` to `endkey`: `endkey=1&descending=true`:

KeyValue





`2``"baz"`

`1``"bar"`

Now that looks a lot better. CouchDB started reading at the bottom of the view and went backward until it hit `endkey`.

Comment: This is a better answer... CouchDB is non-intuitive to a traditional SQL users, but once you understand what it is doing, it does make sense.